# Determine the argument of the table such that two tables have the same value

Tags: summation

Suppose i have

```
A:=Plus @@ Table[2 (Pi/n) (i + 4), {i, 0, n/2, 1}]
B:=Plus @@ Table[ x , {i, (Pi/n), (n/2 + 1) (Pi/n), (Pi/n)}]
```

i need to determine the argument of the table on `B`, such that `A=B` for every $n\in\{2k|k\in\mathbb N\}$ (even numbers).

**My attempt:**
I'm thinking about this summation:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\frac{2\pi}{n}(i+4)=\sum_{i=1}^{n/2 +1}\frac{2\pi}{n}((i-1)+4)=\sum_{i=1}^{n/2 +1}\frac{2\pi}{n}(i+3)$$
So, i got `x=2(i+3)`. But when i test `n=20`, the results were different. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

N.B. If there's something unclear about my question please tell me, i will edit it asap when i get the notification. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = Sum[2 (Pi/n) (i + 4), {i, 0, n/2, 1}];
b = Sum[x, {i, (Pi/n), (n/2 + 1) (Pi/n), (Pi/n)}];
FullSimplify[a == b, Assumptions -> n/2 ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

> `16 + n) π == 2 n x`